# How to fetch only one user from Azure AD B2C using a custom policy with different user matches

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a validation technical profile that checks if there is an existing user with the same company custom attribute during sign up and returns an error.  It works great if there is just one user that matches the company name but throws an error when there are multiple which is possible.

Exception is application insight is:

**Only one retrieved principal can be returned.**

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-CheckDuplicateCompany">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" DefaultValue="NOTFOUND" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdNotFound" DefaultValue="NOTFOUND" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertObjectIdAADUserObjectIdNotFoundAreEqual" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>


<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertObjectIdAADUserObjectIdNotFoundAreEqual" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimsAreEqual">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdNotFound" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase" />
    </InputParameters>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

**AAD-CheckDuplicateCompany** is used as a validation technical profile in **LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail**, so it will not insert the user if there is at least one user that exists with the same company attribute.  Is there a way to get just one user match?

Comment: Yeah you could use the ms graph api to get users

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. It’s only supported to use an input claim that uniquely identifies an account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#inputclaims

You need to make your own REST API call and perform your custom logic there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange?pivots=b2c-custom-policy